# Could not compile stylesheet : XSL transform exception while running from greenplum

Tags: java, xml, xslt, greenplum

I have an xsl which i use to output an xml using the following code...(java 1.6)

```
Source input= new StreamSource(new StringReader( xmlContent));
InputStream xslStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/java.xsl");
if (xslStream == null) {
        xslStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("java.xsl");
}

Transformer transformer = null;
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslStream));//this line throws the exception when run from greenplum

ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
transformer.transform(input, new StreamResult(output));
```

Here is the XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the input XML( i don't think the input xml even matters because the code doesn't even get to the point where it needs to transform the input)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <TestClass xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
 </TestClass>
```

This works just fine when i test this from eclipse/cmd on windows....

But when i deploy the jar to a greenplum box , create a function and then run a query to call the function , i get the following exception

**javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet**

at the following line

> transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslStream));

I print the stack trace for my convenience and this is what i get

```
TransformerFactoryImpl.java:843
TransformerFactoryImpl.java:632
```

Please note that TransformerFactoryImpl is from the java API and not my own class....

I looked up online but nothing helped..i even downloaded the  TransformerFactoryImpl.java source code but couldn't really figure out ...

Any ideas?

Comment: As the stylesheet compiles fine as you say in Eclipse and as I can't see anything wrong with the XSLT code, I would first check that `new StreamSource(xslStream)` really loads that code you think it loads.

Comment: i tried a lot of things..even hardcoded the xsl in code and then did TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl)));  to read directly from a string.....i mean new StreamSource(xslStream) works in eclipse on both linux and windows..so i don't know what can be wrong with it.....

Comment: I only do XSLT,, hopefully someone with knowledge of greenplum can help better.